# $http not working in Angularjs 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

I am stuck with angular's all type of $http requests I am trying to hit the rest API with $http but my code ran through it and do not show any call in chrome network tab. I am using python simplehttpserver for my project execution.

Below is the code of the service I am trying to hit

**HTML CODE**

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" method="post" ng-submit="loginModel.login()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="loginModel.username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginModel.password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-block">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Log In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Controller Code**

module.exports = function ($scope,$rootScope,$state,crudFactory,$http,$resource) {

```
var vm = this;
vm.login = login;

function login() {
    var  userDetail = {
        username:vm.username,
        password:vm.password
    };


    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'http:example.com',
        data:userDetail,
    }).then(function (response) {
       console.log(response)
    }, function (response) {

    });
}
```

I have inject $http in my controller and have also tried to hit the API with $resource but nothing is happening when i hit the service on click event.

I have tried this with core javascript and it works fine but why its not working $http or $resouce

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://www.example.com/", false);
    xhr.send();
    console.log(xhr.status);
```

Please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: Where do you inject `$http`?

Comment: see the question now i have included controller dependency header as well

Comment: You are using a GET method in your XMLHttpRequest and a POST method in $http. Are you needing to use GET?

Comment: I need to use both but not any type of request is hitting the server

Comment: It just simply go through it and sonsole nothing and i dont even see any network XHR call in chrome

Comment: Your `url` in `$http` is also formatted strangely. Try using `https://www.example.com/` as you have in XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I see you are using `module.exports`, are you using Webpack or something similar?

Comment: yes i am using webpack for file bundling

Comment: will that cause any issue ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL is not formatted correctly, and you aren't doing anything in the event of an error.

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'http://example.com',
    data:userDetail,
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
}, function (response) {
   console.log('error response', response);
});
```

This will at least show something in the console if there is an error.

If the url change still isn't working, check your browser developer console's network tab to see if the request is being made and if so, if it is timing out (stuck in pending state)

Comment: The issue was not from the network call but from the start call was not going top server error event work when http hit the server and get response in case of response status.